# Opening and importing Multiple txt or csv files into DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, csv, datagridview, text-files

I have problem with my coding. I want to import multiple text file into DataGridView. But this program I made is keep updating the data when read next file rather than display in in another table.

**Edited**: what I want to find how to edit my code so that another text file data on the other column

```
Private Function loadmultipletxtfile()

    OpenFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\temp\"
    OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt"
    'OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV files (*.csv)|*.CSV"
    OpenFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2
    OpenFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
    Me.OpenFileDialog1.Multiselect = True

    If (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
        For x = 0 To OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count
            Try
                Dim fName As String = ""
                fName = OpenFileDialog1.FileNames(x)
                Me.TextBox1.Text += fName

                Dim TextLine As String = ""

                Dim SplitLine() As String

                If System.IO.File.Exists(fName) = True Then

                    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(fName)
                    table.Columns.Add("Id" & x, Type.GetType("System.Int32"))
                    table.Columns.Add("Angle MX" & x, Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    table.Columns.Add("Angle MY" & x, Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    table.Columns.Add("Angle MXK" & x, Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    table.Columns.Add("Angle MYK" & x, Type.GetType("System.String"))
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = table


                    Do While objReader.Peek() <> -1

                        TextLine = objReader.ReadLine()

                        SplitLine = Split(TextLine, ",")

                        'Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
                        table.Rows.Add(SplitLine)
                        DataGridView1.DataSource = table

                    Loop

                Else

                    MsgBox("File Does Not Exist")

                End If
            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        Next
        MsgBox("Total files loaded = " & OpenFileDialog1.FileNames.Count)
    End If


End Function '
```

Comment: Your description is too vague. Please provide a FULL and CLEAR description of EXACTLY what you're trying to achieve and EXACTLY how what actually happens differs from your expectations. Also, I suspect that you haven't debugged your code so you really need to do that before posting here.  Set a breakpoint and step through the code so that you know EXACTLY where what actually happens deviates from your expectation and EXACTLY what data is in use at that time.  If you don't know how to use breakpoints, now is the time to learn.

Comment: @jmcilhinney i have debug it but i have no idea what going on. The next file data keep updating in the same column rather than next column.

Comment: Debugging is not just running the project in the debugger. Have you set a breakpoint and then stepped through the code? If not then you haven't really debugged. If have debugged properly then you can tell us exactly where things go awry and exactly how, i.e. what line and what data.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Yeah i have debug it but still im blank to find solution to load multiple data into the datagridview. could you give idea a bit to solve my problem .

Comment: If you have debugged properly then you know EXACTLY where the reality of what the code does differs from your expectation of what it does, so you can show us where that is and tell us exactly what data is in use at the time.  If you can't give us that information then you haven't debugged properly.  If you have debugged properly and the code completes without deviating from your expectations but doesn't produce the correct result then the issue is with your expectations, so you need to go back to the drawing board and work out what you want your code to actually do.